# How to package a function for export?

Tags: functions, programming, packages

I often post code for functions on Stack-Exchange, and then later find that they are unexecutable - that people can't use them because I mistakenly omitted some private functions or values that are needed. This function calls that function and that function calls another funciton in a package that I didn't mention, and so forth....

This happens frequently enough that I find myself needing ***a tool that can effectively pull the function up by its roots***, returning just what is needed (certain functions, various symbols, referenced files, parts of packages, etc...) to run the function in an example and nothing more.

I imagine that this would be very useful for visualizing the inner workings of functions in general as well!

Comment: Maybe `FullDefinition` does what you want, assuming you capture its printed output and then export it appropriately — e.g. for a symbol `f` and its dependencies use `FullDefinition[f] // ExportString[#,"Text"]&`.

Comment: FullDefinition would certainly be helpful but omits too much, such as values that are not computed with DelayedSet

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a problem you should try to solve automatically.  Use good code hygiene and make sure you don't call private functions.  You should (aim to) understand your code well enough that you don't get surprises like this --- you wrote it, and you know it better than anyone else.  If there are surprises even to you, how will anyone else understand it?!

Whenever I think I've got a complete snippet of code, I quit the kernel and check it.  It can be a little irritating but that's by far the best time to catch problems.

Comment: +1 for "quit the kernel and check it".  Anyone looking to post a question *should* do this before posting.  It's part of the process of creating a minimal example.